# Angular 9 CLI backward compatibility

Tags: angular

As an organization, we are migrating from Angular 8 to 9. We want to install the Angular 9 CLI globally to our CI server. However, all of our Angular apps use Angular 8.

We want to make sure there are no compatibility issues. Our CI server mainly uses the CLI to run Karma tests and to build bundles.

I can't find documentation which confirms backward compatibility. Perhaps I missed it.

Does Angular normally preserve backward compatibility in this way?

Edit:  We don't want to upgrade our Angular 8 apps to Angular 9 right away.  But we want to use version 9 of the CLI to build the apps.

Comment: You just need to check the changes and differences between `Angular 8` and  `Angular 9`. It doesn't matter to CI comparability.

Answer (score 1):

Try using official [Angular Update Guide](https://update.angular.io/) link and choose the `From` and `To` version to get a list of changes and compatibility.